# How to move ImageView after keyboard appearing?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, scrollview

I have a layout with different views. I need to move layout with header image (eye) after keyboard appearing. First I have situation like on picture 1

[image]

After clicking on Email, all layout is moving, but without header image (eye). Picture 2
[image]

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_eye" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/no_account"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/registration"
        style="@style/TextLink"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:text="@string/entre"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/InputWindow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintEnabled="false">


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="5dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                    android:id="@+id/passwordText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_eye"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/TextLink"
                android:layout_width="109dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/forgetPassword"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/entreBtn"
                style="@style/ButtonDisable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/entire"
                app:cornerRadius="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can not put ImageView into main layout with EditText because ImageView must not be tied with these layouts.

I don't know what to do with this ImageView which did not move upper

Answer (score 0):

The linear layout that holds the views to be below the image view using

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">... And the rest of your views ...
```